# how to parse this: char(x)?

Tags: php, parsing, yaml

I use YAML to get MySQL schema and i need to **parse only these kind of strings** `CHAR(60)` or `VARCHAR(90)` etc..

Parsing result would be like this:

```
array('CHAR', 60);
array('VARCHAR', 90);
```

Comment: I found a better solution: Just visit this URL [preg_match#101618](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#101618), you'll see the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following regex will do it.  If these don't occur one per line, you should also add the `\b` boundaries after the opening slash and before the closing one.

```
$s = "VARCHAR(90)";
$matches = array();
preg_match("/([A-Z]+)\(([0-9]+)\)/", $s, $matches);

// Then use the matched values into your array.
array($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

**EDIT**: Had the `$matches` array keys wrong the first time.  Should be 1 & 2, not 0 & 1.